# How to reuse application constants written inside Java classes within javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, configuration, constants

Is there is a way to reuse `public static final` constants defined inside Java classes with the javascript files ?

Or is there a better way to define such constants so that they can be reused by both java & JavaScript ?

Comment: Can't you just have some functions on the server that let the client read the configurations?

Comment: @Hassan: Probably I am just not aware of how to do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to store your config as [JSON](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) on the server side, then have the server inject that into the HTML response to the client.

The server can read the JSON on startup and keep it in a singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access those strings by referring to the java applet:

SimpleApplet.class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class SimpleApplet extends Applet
{
    public static final int someInt = 1;
    public static int getInt()
    {
        return someInt;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
...
<SCRIPT>
function GetFromJava() { 
   alert("The value of SimpleApplet.someInt is " + document.simple.someInt + "\n"
         "Returned value from SimpleApplet.getInt() is " +  document.simple.getInt());
   }
</SCRIPT>
...
<APPLET CODE="SimpleApplet.class" NAME="simple"  HEIGHT=0 WIDTH=0>
...
```

Also, take a look at [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html).